# What is the sort order of tags in a CV for Careers2.0?

Tags: support, tags, jobs, sorting

You can select tags you want to be displayed in your CV in to "Top [10-20-30]%" section.

But the order seems to follow the the global SO popularity of a tag (i.e. the number of questions on a tag), and not the order of tags of my profile.

If I want certain tags to be **immediately visible** (i.e. **without having to click on "more"**), I need to *not* select other tags I have some knowledge in (while not having done many answers on them), in order to make sure a less popular tag (I am heavily invested in) is visible.

However, should the tag order follow my [own "tags section"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc#tags-table), I wouldn't have this issue, since the tags I want always visible are the ones I am the most active in.

Is my interpretation of the current tag order correct?
Is it possible to have that order follow the user account tags, instead of a global sort order criteria?

Comment: See also another similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91584/ordering-of-the-top-tags-in-careers-profile

Comment: I deleted it. This is in fact an exact dupe, only formulated a bit differently. I didn't see it in the related list.

Comment: Or not be based on any other internal order, but allow me to sort them and reposition them myself...